# SIS model with vaccination

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling, biology

For the simple SIS model
$$ \begin{aligned}
    \mathsf{S}′ &= \Lambda − \beta \mathsf{SI} − \mu \mathsf{S} + \gamma \mathsf{I} \\
    \mathsf{I}′ &= \beta \mathsf{SI} −(\mu+\gamma)\mathsf{I}
\end{aligned} $$
The basic reproduction number $R_0$ is $R_0 = \beta K/(\mu+\gamma)$.

For the model
$$ \begin{aligned}
    \mathsf{S} ′ &= \Lambda(\mathsf{N}) − \beta(\mathsf{N})\mathsf{SI} − (\mu+\phi)\mathsf{S} + \gamma \mathsf{I} + \theta \mathsf{V} \\
    \mathsf{I}′ &= \beta(\mathsf{N})\mathsf{SI} +\sigma\beta(\mathsf{N})\mathsf{VI} −(\mu+\gamma)\mathsf{I} \\
    \mathsf{V}′ &= \phi \mathsf{S}−\sigma\beta(\mathsf{N})\mathsf{VI} −(\mu+\theta)\mathsf{V}
\end{aligned} $$
As $\mathsf{N}=\mathsf{S}+\mathsf{I}+\mathsf{V}$ , this is rewritten as:
$$ \begin{aligned}
    \mathsf{I}′ &= \beta[K−\mathsf{I}−(1−\sigma)\mathsf{V}]\mathsf{I} −(\mu+\gamma)\mathsf{I} \\
    \mathsf{V}′ &= \phi[K−\mathsf{I}]−\sigma\beta \mathsf{V}\mathsf{I} −(\mu+\theta+\phi)\mathsf{V} 
\end{aligned} $$
And the basic reproduction number $R(\phi)$ is $$R(\phi)= \frac{\beta K(\mu+\theta+\sigma\phi)}{(\mu+\gamma)(\mu+\theta+\phi)}\text{.}$$ With a backward bifurcation at $R(\phi)=1$ then the critical reproduction number $R_c$ satisfies

$R_c=\dfrac{\mu+\theta+\sigma\phi}{\mu+\theta+\phi} \cdot \left( \dfrac{\sigma(\mu+\gamma)+2\sqrt{\sigma(1−\sigma)(\mu+\gamma)\phi}−(\mu+\theta+\sigma\phi)}{\sigma(\mu+\gamma)\phi} \right)$

Where $\sigma\beta_c K = \sigma(\mu+\gamma)+2\sqrt{\sigma(1−\sigma)(\mu+\gamma)\phi}−(\mu+\theta+\sigma\phi)$

Now assume we have $\theta=0$.
Given this,

1. Show how to choose $\phi$ to make $R_c$ < $R_0$, assuming that all parameters other
   than $\phi$ are kept fixed.
2. Is it possible to improve the vaccine (decrease $\sigma$) enough to make $R_c < R_0$ ,
   assuming all parameters other than $\sigma$ are kept fixed?

As for part 1), I rewrote $$ R_c= \frac{(\mu+\sigma\phi) R_0}{(\mu+\phi) \phi}$$ to solve the inequality
$\frac{\mu+\sigma\phi}{\phi\mu+\phi^2} <1$ and then used quadratic form and so on, but I’m not sure about part 2) so help is appreciated. And also I’d like to verify that the procedure in 1) is as I wrote.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, I'm submitting an adjusted MathJax version of your question. I'm not 100% certain that I didn't screw up some expressions (one in particular). Can you please check if I've got it right (if and when the update is approved and goes through)?

Comment: Everything  thing is fine, thanks for helping with the editing!